# Converting HTML to XML

Tags: html, xml

I have got hundereds of HTML files that need to be conveted in XML. We are using these HTML to  serve contents for applications but now we have to serve these contents as XML.

HTML files are contains, tables, div's, image's, p's, b or strong tags, etc..

I googled and found some applications but i couldn't achive yet.

Could you suggest a way to convert these file contents to XML?

Comment: Remember that HTML and XML are two distinct concepts in the tree of markup languages. You can't exactly [replace HTML with XML](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_whatis.asp) . XML can be viewed as a generalized form of HTML, but even that is imprecise. You mainly use HTML to display data, and XML to carry(or store) the data. This link is helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472162/how-to-read-html-as-xml [More here - difference between HTML and XML](http://www.prlog.org/10063329-know-difference-between-xml-and-html.html)

Comment: Have a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/85922/938089). Then, have a very close look at the [fourth comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/84556/#comment1436887_85922). Why do you want to convert HTML to XML?

Comment: @RobW i will check it. We were serving HTML as a content for some applications but now we have to serve as XML.

Comment: @RobW, also i know the differences between XML and HTML. But i need to parse its content and put in XML.

Comment: @bahadirarslan: you'd need to say for which purpose you want to do this. At worst, you could have a dumb XML representation of an HTML document putting each character into its own element if you wanted to (that's probably not what you want, but you would have turned your HTML document into XML).

Comment: @bahadir HTML parsers tolerate much more than XML. If you're lucky, turning it into a [XHTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML) document, by prefixing `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">` is sufficient for you (wrap scripts in `<script>` blocks in `//<![CDATA[<newline> ...content... //]]></script>` sections). When your HTML is not [well-formed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_element), you have to look for a HTML parser, which offers an Export-as-XML option.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read HTML as XML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472162/how-to-read-html-as-xml)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I was successful using `tidy` command line utility. On linux I installed it quickly with `apt-get install tidy`. Then the command:

`tidy -q -asxml --numeric-entities yes source.html >file.xml`

gave an xml file, which I was able to process with xslt processor. However I needed to set up xhtml1 dtds correctly.

This is their homepage: [html-tidy.org](http://www.html-tidy.org/) (and the legacy one: [HTML Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/))

Comment: There is also xmllint -html -xmlout

Comment: I also use it sometimes. I think you should make a separate answer from it.

Comment: does it remove javascript from html file

Comment: This often works, but with some HTML5 documents, I get empty output.

Comment: First glance at Tidy's homepage tells that they haven't updated the project since 2008. This may explain problems.

Comment: The new (modern) tidy homepage can be found at: http://www.html-tidy.org

Answer (score 3):

I did found a way to convert (even bad) html into well formed XML. I started to base this on the DOM loadHTML function. However during time several issues occurred and I optimized and added patches to correct side effects.

```
  function tryToXml($dom,$content) {
    if(!$content) return false;

    // xml well formed content can be loaded as xml node tree
    $fragment = $dom->createDocumentFragment();
    // wonderfull appendXML to add an XML string directly into the node tree!

    // aappendxml will fail on a xml declaration so manually skip this when occurred
    if( substr( $content,0, 5) == '<?xml' ) {
      $content = substr($content,strpos($content,'>')+1);
      if( strpos($content,'<') ) {
        $content = substr($content,strpos($content,'<'));
      }
    }

    // if appendXML is not working then use below htmlToXml() for nasty html correction
    if(!@$fragment->appendXML( $content )) {
      return $this->htmlToXml($dom,$content);
    }

    return $fragment;
  }



  // convert content into xml
  // dom is only needed to prepare the xml which will be returned
  function htmlToXml($dom, $content, $needEncoding=false, $bodyOnly=true) {

    // no xml when html is empty
    if(!$content) return false;

    // real content and possibly it needs encoding
    if( $needEncoding ) {
      // no need to convert character encoding as loadHTML will respect the content-type (only)
      $content =  '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset='.$this->encoding.'">' . $content;
    }

    // return a dom from the content
    $domInject = new DOMDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");
    $domInject->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $domInject->formatOutput = true;

    // html type
    try {
      @$domInject->loadHTML( $content );
    } catch(Exception $e){
      // do nothing and continue as it's normal that warnings will occur on nasty HTML content
    }
        // to check encoding: echo $dom->encoding
        $this->reworkDom( $domInject );

    if( $bodyOnly ) {
      $fragment = $dom->createDocumentFragment();

      // retrieve nodes within /html/body
      foreach( $domInject->documentElement->childNodes as $elementLevel1 ) {
       if( $elementLevel1->nodeName == 'body' and $elementLevel1->nodeType == XML_ELEMENT_NODE ) {
         foreach( $elementLevel1->childNodes as $elementInject ) {
           $fragment->insertBefore( $dom->importNode($elementInject, true) );
         }
        }
      }
    } else {
      $fragment = $dom->importNode($domInject->documentElement, true);
    }

    return $fragment;
  }



    protected function reworkDom( $node, $level = 0 ) {

        // start with the first child node to iterate
        $nodeChild = $node->firstChild;

        while ( $nodeChild )  {
            $nodeNextChild = $nodeChild->nextSibling;

            switch ( $nodeChild->nodeType ) {
                case XML_ELEMENT_NODE:
                    // iterate through children element nodes
                    $this->reworkDom( $nodeChild, $level + 1);
                    break;
                case XML_TEXT_NODE:
                case XML_CDATA_SECTION_NODE:
                    // do nothing with text, cdata
                    break;
                case XML_COMMENT_NODE:
                    // ensure comments to remove - sign also follows the w3c guideline
                    $nodeChild->nodeValue = str_replace("-","_",$nodeChild->nodeValue);
                    break;
                case XML_DOCUMENT_TYPE_NODE:  // 10: needs to be removed
                case XML_PI_NODE: // 7: remove PI
                    $node->removeChild( $nodeChild );
                    $nodeChild = null; // make null to test later
                    break;
                case XML_DOCUMENT_NODE:
                    // should not appear as it's always the root, just to be complete
                    // however generate exception!
                case XML_HTML_DOCUMENT_NODE:
                    // should not appear as it's always the root, just to be complete
                    // however generate exception!
                default:
                    throw new exception("Engine: reworkDom type not declared [".$nodeChild->nodeType. "]");
            }
            $nodeChild = $nodeNextChild;
        } ;
    }
```

Now this also allows to add more html pieces into one XML which I needed to use myself. In general it can be used like this:

```
        $c='<p>test<font>two</p>';
    $dom=new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

$n=$dom->appendChild($dom->createElement('info')); // make a root element

if( $valueXml=tryToXml($dom,$c) ) {
  $n->appendChild($valueXml);
}
    echo '<pre/>'. htmlentities($dom->saveXml($n)). '</pre>';
```

In this example `'<p>test<font>two</p>'` will nicely be outputed in well formed XML as '`<info><p>test<font>two</font></p></info>`'. The info root tag is added as it will also allow to convert '`<p>one</p><p>two</p>`' which is not XML as it has not one root element. However if you html does for sure have one root element then the extra root `<info>` tag can be skipped.

With this I'm getting real nice XML out of unstructured and even corrupted HTML!

I hope it's a bit clear and might contribute to other people to use it.