# How to get a clean xml representation from a website url

Tags: java, xml, dom, sax, htmlcleaner

I'm trying to get a clean representation of a website url, so
I can put the 'html' inside a

```
org.w3c.dom.Document
```

to be able to do further processing with xpath and so on.

What I get, when I try to put the html inside a document is :

org.xml.sax.SAXParseException : Elementtyp "link" muss mit dem entsprechenden Endtag "" beendet werden

which means, that "link" has to be closed, what isn't the case in this website.

So, could be the right approach ?
Should I 'fix' the document and replace errors ?

I tried net.sourceforge.htmlcleaner but it didn't figure out, how to
'fix' the errors.

Any help ?

Regards,
Holger

Comment: It depends what the HTML cleaner does to the HTML. Valid HTML is not necessarily valid XML - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473875/converting-html-to-xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML is usually not xml, so Document can not process it. You need a special library like [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/)

Comment: I don't think JSoup generates org.w3c.dom compliant Documents, they are not parsable with XPath.

Comment: @GuillaumeSerre: yes, but jsoup supports jquery-like selectors which may be more suitable for working with html.

Comment: I'm just trying it out, and it's pretty nice.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at Neko : http://nekohtml.sourceforge.net/

Works terribly well for me