# How to build a Google Sitemap XML file from HTML

Tags: xml-sitemap

As part of SEO, I need to submit a website's sitemap to Google. But Google is rejecting it saying it is an HTML file and it needs an XML file. How does one convert HTML to XML? I've searched the Google Webmasters page and the net for answers but came up with nothing. Really appreciate it if someone could give some guidance on how to do this!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting HTML to XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473875/converting-html-to-xml)

Comment: You can't simply convert your HTML sitemap, have a read here: https://www.google.com/search?q=google+xml+sitemap+generator, https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183668?hl=en&ref_topic=8476, https://code.google.com/p/sitemap-generators/wiki/SitemapGenerators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't want to convert your HTML sitemap to XML, you want to create an XML sitemap from scratch according to Google's [sitemap specifications](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183668?hl=en)

You can either make this by hand in a text editor like notepad++, build a script to generate it, or use one of these tools: http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/