# No MouseHover Effect

Tags: html, xml

I am trying to get the mousehover effect in xml, but no idea. However i followed a tutorial from youtube and tried working with html first.

However,I can not see the mouse hover effect .
BY the way I followed this link on youtube.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-jfQeqd0eqc

Please help me out. One more thing I would like to know how can i convert it to xml.That is my final objective at this point.

Here is my html code.

```
<html>
<head>
        <title>Nihar</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
    <img src="wheel.jpeg" onmouseover="src='wheel.jpeg'" onmouseout="src='wheel.jpeg'"">
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: image on mouseover mouseout and src are same .. for effect donot u think at least 1 image need to be diff..? for html to xml check this- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473875/converting-html-to-xml

Comment: thanks Neha ,I was watching the video in low resolution and the name the guy had used are too identical.
why dint u post it as ans though ??

Comment: :) its ok u solve issue its matter ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The images are the same. You have to provide a different image for the onmouseover handler