# I want to try a tag not closed with xpath

Tags: xslt, xpath

I want to try a tag not closed with xpath like this:

```
<figure class="img"><img class="immagine-in-linea-senza-cornice" width="16%" src="images/schema_1_fmt.jpeg" alt=""/>
```

I want to close the tag  with a xslt transformation.

Comment: Something is missing in your post, and I don't think you can use xpath/xslt on a non-valid xml file because it won't be parsed. You should treat it like a text-file

Comment: You could try running it through htmlTidy which will put in closing tags for you, then do your XSLT processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XPath does not work directly on the input document, but on an abstract, tree-like representation of the document (e.g. [XDM](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-datamodel/) or [DOM](http://www.w3.org/DOM/)). In this model, opening and closing tags of an element are not represented at all. Instead, an element appears as a single entity in the tree.

Therefore, manipulating `<` and `/>` is completely out of the question for languages like XPath, because the concept of opening and closing tags is simply not implemented. I would argue that this abstraction is an advantage of the models, though.

Also, XSLT transformations normally take as input XML documents. If your document has unclosed elements, it will be rejected by any application that is only prepared to process XML.

In short, fix the XML document with a language other than the combination of XSLT and XPath (see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473875/converting-html-to-xml)), and think about XSLT as soon as you have well-formed XML as input.