# I need to convert HTML To XML as my server only accepts XML- other answers don't solve this

Tags: html, xml

****This is a simple HTML code for a form for vehicle search
I have the CSS AND JAVASCRIPT ready for this . Want to convert HTML to XML

---

```
<div class="landingSearch">
  <h2>Find your next vehicle</h2>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <form name="search" id="searchForm" action="http://localhost:8888/inventory"
    method="get">
    <select id="make" name="make">
      <option value="">All Makes</option>
    </select> 
    <select id="model" name="model">
      <option value="">All Models</option>
    </select> 
    <select id="condition" name="condition">
      <option value="">All</option>
      <option>new</option>
      <option>used</option>
    </select> 
    <input type="text" name="zipCode" id="zip" placeholder="Zip Code"    pattern="\d*"
    only-digits="" required="" value="" tabindex="0" aria-required="true"
    aria-invalid="true" /> 
    <input type="hidden" id="state" value="TX" /> 
    <button type="find cars" id="inventorySearchButton">Find Cars</button></form>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting HTML to XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473875/converting-html-to-xml)

Comment: I didnot get any help there Hunter