# Converting HTML file to XML file

Tags: xml, html

I have been asked to convert a HTML file to XML file however I have no idea on where to start.

Would it be possible to guide me on where to start in order to achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: whats the content of the HTML file? what's it actually related to?

Comment: All it is is a homepage however the client does not know html but knows XML so they want it to be converted to XML in order to make changes,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473875/converting-html-to-xml