# "Opening and ending tag mismatch" of `xmlstarlet sel`

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xmlstarlet

http://doi.cnki.net/Resolution/Handler?doi=10.13345/j.cjb.180087

When I run `xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//i[@class = "iconSucc"]/@class'` on the following file, I got the following error messages. Does anybody know how to fix the problem?

```
-:77.294: Opening and ending tag mismatch: img line 77 and a
 middle;" src="/Content/images/gongshangbiaoshi.gif" alt="" class="footpic"></a>
                                                                               ^
-:77.301: Opening and ending tag mismatch: a line 77 and span
;" src="/Content/images/gongshangbiaoshi.gif" alt="" class="footpic"></a></span>
                                                                               ^
-:77.332: Opening and ending tag mismatch: span line 77 and p
i.gif" alt="" class="footpic"></a></span><br />©2014-2018中国知网(CNKI) </p
                                                                               ^
-:79.15: Opening and ending tag mismatch: p line 74 and div
        </div>
              ^
-:92.8: Opening and ending tag mismatch: div line 61 and body
</body>
       ^
-:93.8: Opening and ending tag mismatch: body line 11 and html
</html>
       ^
-:94.1: Premature end of data in tag html line 2

^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML file is not *well-formed*. The `<img>` element at line 77

```
<img style="height: 24px; border: 0px none; vertical-align: middle;" src="/Content/images/gongshangbiaoshi.gif" alt="" class="footpic" >
```

is not closed. Add a closing tag `... />` to make it *well-formed*:

```
<img style="height: 24px; border: 0px none; vertical-align: middle;" src="/Content/images/gongshangbiaoshi.gif" alt="" class="footpic" />
```

Then the output will be:

> iconSucc

**EDIT:**

Using `xmllint`, you can achieve the result with one command:

```
xmllint -html -xmlout Handler.xml | xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//i[@class = "iconSucc"]/@class'
```

Comment: Is there a way to automatically make the input HTML well-formed? lxml does not have this problem if the input is not well-formed.

Comment: Google for "Converting HTML to well formed XML". Or, using StackOverflow suggestions, have a look at this question: [Converting HTML to well formed XML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10473875/1305969). `tidy` seems to be a hot candidate.

Comment: I added a one-line solution using `xmllint`.