# Publish generic HTML report in Azure DevOps release pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, report, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-extensions

I am working on publishing generic html report in Azure Devops release pipeline but not able to get any useful extension or approach to achieve it.

Also got a link in which same ticket is opened from two years in developer community.

Link: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/support-for-generic-html-publishing-inside-build-a/491426

Thank you,
Shivam

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the following task :

PublishTestResults@2

E.g. This is what I use to publish a test result from the OWASP code analysis app

```
- task: PublishTestResults@2
  displayName: 'Publish Dependency Check Test Results'
  inputs:
    testResultsFiles: 'dependency-check-junit.xml'
    searchFolder: '/home/vsts/work/1/TestResults/dependency-check/'
    testRunTitle: 'Dependency Check'
```

What you need to do is create a report following the formatting specification described in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-test-results?view=azure-devops&tabs=trx%2Cyaml) and target the directory where you saved (searchFolder) it (and possibly the name of the file in testResultsFiles) in the publishtestresults task.

The owasp task I am referencing is this:

```
dependency-check.dependencycheck.dependency-check-build-task.dependency-check-build-task@6
```

and here is the code for the whole task if you want to test it in your application (we analyze a package.json and package-lock.json in our case)

```
- task: dependency-check.dependencycheck.dependency-check-build-task.dependency-check-build-task@6
  displayName: 'Dependency Check'
  inputs:
    projectName: dependencies-check
    scanPath: '**/*.json'
    warnOnCVSSViolation: true
    format: 'ALL'
  continueOnError: true

- task: PublishTestResults@2
  displayName: 'Publish Dependency Check Test Results'
  inputs:
    testResultsFiles: 'dependency-check-junit.xml'
    searchFolder: '/home/vsts/work/1/TestResults/dependency-check/'
    testRunTitle: 'Dependency Check'
```

the result will be displayed in your pipeline screen under Tests
[image]

Comment: Thank you @Danilo for the above pointer, however I am trying to publish generic html report and there is no xml file I am getting in my pipeline flow.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to publish HTML reports using a task from Azure (MS), you may be able to test an application like [this one](https://github.com/JakubRumpca/azure-pipeline-html-report), but the fact that has not bee updated since Jan 2021 may be a problem.
You may have some luck using what is described in this question: [convert html to xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473875/converting-html-to-xml), but again, you would need to format it to match Azure req.