# How can I loop through a string, replacing sections that match a pattern?

Tags: c#

I have the following HTML markup

```
<p>xxxx</p>
 <pre>xxx</pre>
 <p>xxxx</p>
 <pre>yyy</pre>
```

I need to be able to change this to:

```
<p>xxxx</p>
 <pre>ABC xxx ABC</pre>
 <p>xxxx</p>
 <pre>ABC yyy ABC </pre>
```

I had a suggestion to use:

```
   var loDoc = XDocument.Parse(lcHTML);
   foreach (XElement loElement in loDoc.Descendants("pre"))
```

This does extract all the pre elements but it doesn't give me a way to tie things together and reinsert code into the original string.

Is there another way I could do this that would allow me to make the code change I need. I was thinking of using split and splitting on the `<pre>..</pre>` but then that would not really give me what I need as I need to replace the code inside the `<pre>...</pre>`

Comment: Sound like a job for [RegexMan][1]! (I don't really know how you use regex with XDocument, though...)


  [1]: http://xkcd.com/208/

Comment: I'd actually rather not use XDocument. It seems like overkill and this is actually not even a valid document as it doesn't have a starting and ending <>.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to use [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) but it has to be valid XHTML and you need to introduce a root node:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var doc = XDocument.Parse(
            @"<html>
              <p>xxxx</p>
              <pre>xxx</pre>
              <p>xxxx</p>
              <pre>yyy</pre>
            </html>"
        );
        foreach (var pre in doc.Descendants("pre"))
        {
            pre.Value = string.Format("ABC {0} ABC", pre.Value);         
        }
        Console.WriteLine(doc);
    }
}
```

Another possibility is to use [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/):

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(
            @"<p>xxxx</p>
              <pre>xxx</pre>
              <p>xxxx</p>
              <pre>yyy</pre>"
        );
        foreach (var pre in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("pre"))
        {
            pre.InnerHtml = string.Format("ABC {0} ABC", pre.InnerHtml);         
        }
        Console.WriteLine(doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Darin, Doing this does it still keep my original: <p>xxxx</p> and the code before and after all the <pre> elements?

Comment: Yes it keeps it. It only changes the value of `<pre>` elements.

Comment: Darin. I will try this out now. Thanks.

Comment: Darin, Still trying this out. One thing I noticed in your answer was the comment "has to be valid XHTML". Does this mean to say that if my source was to by accident contain a <p> without a closing </p> that I would have a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Get the XML Doc element from this link [How to read HTML as XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472162/how-to-read-html-as-xml)

using the doc element, try

```
XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement; 

XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("pre"); 

foreach (XmlNode node in nodes) {
   node.value = "ABC" + node.value + "ABC";
}
```

Comment: T Doing this does it still keep my original: <p>xxxx</p> and the code before and after all the <pre> elements?

Comment: This is simple as 

str = "ABC" + str + "ABC". The old value of the str is appended with ABC on both sides and it is assigned to the str again. Any code which is using this instance of str. will have the new value. Here , node.value will update the node

Comment: Can you explain how I can put my data into the doc.DocumentElement? One problem I have is that my XML may not be valid?

Comment: Cant understand ur question. Your task is to get the 'doc' variable. Thats all. Use that doc variable in the code i pasted. You should get the output what u want. I also gave a link for obtaining the doc variable

Answer (score 0):

How about using Strings instead of xml?

```
String xmlString = ... \\ get string representation from somewhere
xmlString = xmlString.Replace( "<pre>", "<pre>ABC " ); 
xmlString = xmlString.Replace( "</pre>", " ABC </pre>" );
```