# innerHTML: How To Avoid

Tags: javascript, xml-serialization, firefox-addon

I'm writing a plugin which will convert emoticons to images in a text block for a particular site.  The easy answer is to use regular expressions to detect the trigger text on the innerHTML and insert the img tag, then pipe the string back to the dom element in the *innerHTML* part.  The DOM element block may already have anchor `<a>` and/or text formatting `<b>,<i>,<u>` in the innerHTML part.

For example

```
    var textBlock = pItems[i].innerHTML;
    var kissSource = 'https://mail.google.com/mail/e/35D';
    textBlock = textBlock.replace(/(^|[^&lt;]|[^&gt;]):\*/g, "<img class='emoticon' src='" + kissSource + "' />");
 -->      pItems[i].innerHTML = textBlock;  //<-can I avoid this to be in compliance with Mozilla addons reqmnts
```

I searched for quite a few hours on how I might convert a DOM (or HTML string) to XML (I know: HTML!=XLM [How to read HTML as XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472162/how-to-read-html-as-xml) but perhaps a portion of a div?)  which in turn could be converted to JSON who in turn .. could be converted back into a DOM following: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/School_tutorial/DOM_Building_and_HTML_Insertion?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=XUL_School%2FDOM_Building_and_HTML_Insertion#JSON_Templating

I do not know jQuery, so please if it is possible with javascript that would be ideal.

Should I be solving this problem without running the regular expression against the innerHTML thus avoiding the problme?

Thanks so much, JennaS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Working Solution

Based on your recent comment to @Giuseppe, and your malformed  styling that you borrowed from my post the only solution would be to avoid recursion or iterating through the text strings looking for matching elements for your regEx.

1. Apply the regex to your string as you are proposing.
2. Once finished build a DOM from that string using a HTMLify string parser
3. Replace the node with the new DOM node built from the string.

NB: This is also useful when pulling in AJAX HTML page and you need to parse the HTML results in a temporary DOM object but don't want to merely dump the contents into a the  innerHTML of a newly created element.  Also note that using createDocumentFragment will not be suitable as you cannot navigate a fragment like a DOM tree.

The steps sound hard but there are a few great posts on Stackoverflow which make it easy!
After doing research for you and running into [a now obsolete solution](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/HTML_to_DOM#Using_a_hidden_browser_element_to_parse_HTML_to_a_window.27s_DOM) and [dom parsers which won't work for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579666/getelementsbytagname-equivalent-for-textnodes) I came across a solution from @rob-w: [a dom parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250545/javascript-domparser-access-innerhtml-and-other-properties/9251106#9251106)

Your code would include the DOM parser from @rob-w link plus:

```
     /* 
      * DOMParser HTML extension 
      * 2012-02-02 
      * 
      * By Eli Grey, http://eligrey.com 
      * Public domain. 
      * NO WARRANTY EXPRESSED OR IMPLIED. USE AT YOUR OWN RISK. 
      */
     /*! @source https://gist.github.com/1129031 */
     /*global document, DOMParser*/ 
             (function (DOMParser) {
         "use strict";
         var DOMParser_proto = DOMParser.prototype;
         var real_parseFromString = DOMParser_proto.parseFromString;

         // Firefox/Opera/IE throw errors on unsupported types  
         try {
             // WebKit returns null on unsupported types  
             if ((new DOMParser).parseFromString("", "text/html")) {
                 // text/html parsing is natively supported  
                 return;
             }
         } catch (ex) {}

         DOMParser_proto.parseFromString = function (markup, type) {
             if (/^\s*text\/html\s*(?:;|$)/i.test(type)) {
                 var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("");
                 var doc_elt = doc.documentElement;
                 var first_elt;

                 doc_elt.innerHTML = markup;
                 first_elt = doc_elt.firstElementChild;

                 if (doc_elt.childElementCount === 1 && first_elt.localName.toLowerCase() === "html") {
                     doc.replaceChild(first_elt, doc_elt);
                 }

                 return doc;
             } else {
                 return real_parseFromString.apply(this, arguments);
             }
         };
     }(DOMParser));

     autostyle = function (str) {
         var boldPattern = /(?![^<]*<\/a>)(^|<.>|[\s\W_])\*(\S.*?\S)\*($|<\/.>|[\s\W_])/g;
         var italicsPattern = /(?![^<]*<\/a>)(^|<.>|[\s\W])_(\S.*?\S)_($|<\/.>|[\s\W])/g;
         var strikethroughPattern = /(?![^<]*<\/a>)(^|<.>|[\s\W_])-(\S.*?\S)-($|<\/.>|[\s\W_])/gi;
         var underlinePattern = /(?![^<]*<\/a>)(^|<.>|[\s\W_])!(\S.*?\S)!($|<\/.>|[\s\W_])/gi;
         str = str.replace(strikethroughPattern, '$1<s>$2</s>$3');
         str = str.replace(italicsPattern, '$1<i>$2</i>$3');
         str = str.replace(boldPattern, '$1<b>$2</b>$3');
         str = str.replace(underlinePattern, '$1<u>$2</u>$3');
         return str;
     };

     emoticonRegexFunction = function(str) {
         //do something
         return str;
     }

     RegexWithoutInnerHTML = function () {
         pItems = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
         for (var k = 0; k < pItems.length; k++) {
             var str = pItems[k].textContent;
             str = autostyle(str);
             str = emoticonRegexFunction(str);
             var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString('<p>' + str + '</p>', 'text/html');
             pItems[k].parentNode.replaceChild(doc.getElementsByTagName('p')[0], pItems[k]);
             //       pItems[k].innerHTML = str;  //<-now do not need innerHTML
         }
     };
```

Full working example on jsbin at: http://jsbin.com/itiwek/12/edit

Enjoy.

Comment: Much less fighting with code - @mike-wolfe for the win.  So did you seriously have 10 more edits since your first response.  Thanks so much for fighting on this and figuring it out.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want to convert say ":)" to an emoticon. To do that, you need to parse the text and replace those characters with an img element. So you want to do something like:

```
<script>

function toArray(collection) {
  var arr = [];
  for (var i=0, iLen=collection.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    arr[i] = collection[i];
  }
  return arr;
}

function replaceTextWithEmoticon(el) {
  var re0 = /\:\)/g;
  var emo0 = document.createElement('img');
  emo0.src = 'https://mail.google.com/mail/e/35D'; 
  var node, txt, frag;
  var nodes = toArray(el.childNodes);

  for (var i=0, iLen=nodes.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    node = nodes[i];

    // If it's an element node, process the content
    if (node.nodeType == 1) {
      replaceTextWithEmoticon(node);

    // If it's a text node, look for matching text and replace with emoticon
    } else if (node.nodeType == 3 && re0.test(node.data)) {
      txt = node.data.split(re0);
      frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

      for (var j=0, jLen=txt.length - 1; j<jLen; j++) {

        frag.appendChild(document.createTextNode(txt[j]));
        frag.appendChild(emo0.cloneNode(false));
      }

      if (txt[j] && txt[j].length) {
        frag.appendChild(document.createTextNode(txt[j]));
      }
    }
    node.parentNode.replaceChild(frag, node);
  }
}

</script>

<p id="p0">here is a smily:) and another two:):)</p>
<button onclick="
  replaceTextWithEmoticon(document.getElementById('p0'));
">Replace with emoticon</button>
```

The above needs to be modified to deal with multiple different emoticons in each text node, but I think you get the idea.

Comment: Complicated but it works!  This is really cool.  If I'm following correctly you are splitting the text once a emoticon is detected and then inserting the emo0 img element and then appending the rest of the text.  Would this work with a <p> who already has a <a> anchor element (nodeType==1?).  Thanks a million @RobG !

Comment: Yes, I've updated it to handle nested elements, it was failing because the childNodes collection is live. Converting to to an array solves that issue. The usual trick of going backwards over the childNodes didn't work in Firefox, it kept throwing an error.

Answer (score 1):

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jEqEv/1/)**

Take advantage of the tools available. You can navigate down the DOM from the element you already have stored in pItems. The first image tag, you will alter the src. This will work:

```
pItems[i].getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src = kissSource;
```

Comment: I looked at the jsFiddle Demo.  Essentially I am trying to detect an emoticon within a <p> block.  There is no <img> block yet.  That is what the regex was adding in the example, but if I'm trying to avoid altering the innerHTML directly this will not work.  Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @JennaS - I am not familiar with the requirement on `innerHTML` being excluded. But if you do find a match for an emoticon and there is no image element already, you should manipulate the DOM with `appendChild` or `removeChild` in order to avoid `innerHTML`. You could do this by iterating through the child elements of `pItems` and checking to see if they contained the emoticon and then essentially recreate that element and add in the image with `var img = document.createElement("img");img.src=kissSource;recreatedElement.appendChild(img);`

Comment: Ok - I'll try that @Travis.  The feedback I had from Mozilla Add-on was `1. Markup should not be passed to innerHTML dynamically.
Warning: Due to both security and performance reasons, innerHTML should not be set using dynamic values. This can lead to security issues or fairly serious performance degradation.`

Comment: What possible "security reasons" are there with innerHTML and dynamic values? I think that's a Furphy. And I doubt there are any performance issues either.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to comment on other's posts but if you add a filter to @RobG response it will get you there. (PS: I did submit a code edit suggestion)

```
....
var nodes = toArray(el.childNodes);

if (node.nodeName != "#text") //will allow embedded <b> <img> <a> etc to work.
   continue;

for (var i=0, iLen=nodes.length; i<iLen; i++) {
   ....

<p id="p0">here is a smily:) and <b>another</b> <a href="www.google.com">google</a> two:):) <i>italics</i></p>
    ....
```

Or if you want to expressly look for certain elements to skip such as `<B>` or `<IMG>` or `<A>` etc.

Comment: Thanks you can see the full example at: [http://jsbin.com/itiwek/2](http://jsbin.com/itiwek/2)

Answer (score 1):

This is the same issue I have to obtain the full review on my Addon ([ImageZone](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/imagezone/)).

I think is not a good idea for you to use innerHTML, since you will lost all event listeners registered on the targets node. I think you could use a code like this:

```
var treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(
 node,
 NodeFilter.SHOW_ALL,
 { acceptNode:function (node) {
         return node.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE ? 
                  NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT : NodeFilter.FILTER_REJECT;
 }},false);

 or just

var treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(
 node,
 NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,
 { acceptNode:function (node) {return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT; }},false);

 while(treeWalker.nextNode()) {
     var n=walker.currentNode;
     var text=n.nodeValue;
     var a= text.split(/(--- your emoticon regexp code ---))/g);
     if (a.length > 1){
         n.insertAfter(document.createTextNode(a[0]));
         var img=document.createElement("img");
         switch (a[1]){
             case '...': img.setAttribute('src','...'); break;
         } 
         // or img.setAttribute('src',emos_srcs[a[1]]);

         n.insertAfter(img);
         n.insertAfter(document.createTextNode(a[2]));
         n.parentNode.removeChild(n);
     }

 }
```

Comment: Thanks Giuseppe - Will try that out.  The above code from @MikeWolfe worked for the most part but started breaking down with more nesting.  I got frustrated and then just attempted to get approval with innerHTML.  I most certainly will try your code out!

Comment: ps: how did you figure out the "NO RESTART" option for your plugin?

Comment: Change your install.rdf file by adding: <em:bootstrap>true</em:bootstrap> 

create bootstrap.js (out on the root), implementing: install,uninstall,startup,shutdown. 

-startup:
        Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm");
        AddonManager.getAddonByID("your id", function(addon) {
            include(addon.getResourceURI("chrome/content/myapp.js").spec);//impl include
        });
     
-myapp.js: programmatically add xul elements
-shutdown: remove xul elems etc.
-install and uninstall setup the app.

finally remove every xul references.

Comment: Thanks Giuseppe.  I have been trying to do a mix between @RobG and your code.  I am having problems with the recursion, or whether in fact recursion is the best choice.  If I have to make several replacement emoticons I will need to cycle through all the images and also run the code on the resulting new node.  I am missing something.  Would you terribly mind taking a look at: [link]http://jsbin.com/iqiqoq/4/edit  Would you recommending running through the page over and over until there is no changes, or recursion.

Comment: when you use treeWalker all nodes you insert, will be trafersed too I suppose. So you can traverse with treeWalker, store matching textNodes into an array, then process all array nodes. If you should format the text nodes, try to create a root node, tokenize the text (Ex. split/[*_\_!]/) traverse the split array; if you find a text add a textNode to root; if you find a token add an element and set it as a root node (try also to understand if it is a closing token, in which case go back to parent). At the end insert all root child in place of the original textNode.