# Javascript/RegEx to add <b> tags around filenames

Tags: javascript, regex

What I want to do is find all filenames/filepaths on the page, and make them bold using javascript.

Some example filenames/paths would be:

- \server\folder
- \server\folder\
- \server\folder\filename.txt
- c:\
- c:\folder
- c:\folder\
- c:\folder\filename.txt

The following sample will look for a string using a regular expression pattern 'test.t..' and turn it bold (ie, would find test.txt and it would be bolded). I need to change that regex to one that will find filenames/filepaths instead (just used an easy example, haven't had any luck with the filename/filepath regex myself).

```
findAndReplace(document);

function findAndReplace(root) {
var children = root.childNodes;
var pattern = new RegExp('test.t..', 'ig');
var node;
for(var i = 0, l = children.length; i < l; i++) {
    node = children[i];
    if(node.nodeType === 3) { // we have a text node
      if (node.nodeValue.match(pattern)){
      var newValue = "<b>" + node.nodeValue.match(pattern) + "</b>";
      node.parentElement.outerHTML = node.parentElement.outerHTML.replace(pattern, newValue);
      }

    } else if(node.nodeType === 1) { // Element node
        findAndReplace(node);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You should look at the answers provided to [innerHTML: How To Avoid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15422494/innerhtml-how-to-avoid). The basic strategy is to recurs over element content looking for text nodes. Then slice text strings into text nodes of matching and non–matching text. Then wrap the matches in a B element.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pattern to try:

```
var pattern = /([a-z]:)?(\\\w+)+(\\|\.\w{3,4})?/;
```

Explanation:

```
([a-z]:)?        -  optionally starts with a drive letter and colon
\\               -  backslash
\w+              -  folder name
(\\\w+)+         -  several subfolders possible
(\\|\.\w{3,4})?  -  optionally ends with a backslash or file extension
                    note that the file name would be caught by (\\\w+)+
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer: http://jsfiddle.net/dCE9k/1/

I changed your code a little, see the fiddle for a working example.

The regex should look like this:

`/([a-zA-Z]:)?([\/\\])([a-zA-Z0-9\.]\2?)*/ig;`

It takes care about drive letters, captures the directory delimiter and reuses it throughout the file path. Allows uppercase, lowercase, numbers and dots as a valid file name.

I used this demo HTML code

```
<p>\server\folder</p>
<p>\server\folder\</p>
<p>\server\folder\filename.txt</p>
<p>c:\</p>
<p>c:\folder</p>
<p>c:\folder\</p>
<p>c:\folder\filename.txt</p>
```

And I tweaked a bit your JS code:

```
findAndReplace(document);

function findAndReplace(root) {
    var children = root.childNodes;
    var pattern = /([a-zA-Z]:)?([\/\\])([a-zA-Z0-9\.]\2?)*/ig; // applied new regex
    var node;

    for(var i = 0, l = children.length; i < l; i++) {
        node = children[i];
        if(node.nodeType === 3) { // we have a text node
            if (pattern.test(node.nodeValue)){ // This line changed (maybe not required)
                var newValue = "<b>" + node.nodeValue.match(pattern) + "</b>";
                node.parentElement.innerHTML = newValue; // This line changed
            }
        } else if(node.nodeType === 1) { // Element node
            findAndReplace(node);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I try your code, but it does not work ... even if i corrected the regexp...

So there is the solution:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>My Page</title>
    <script>
    function findAndReplace(root) {
        var children = root.childNodes;
        var pattern = /([a-zA-Z]:[\\\/]|[\\\/])(\w+[\\\/])*\w+\.\w{3}/g;
        var node;
        for(var i = 0, l = children.length; i < l; i++) {
            node = children[i];
            if(node.nodeType === 3) { // we have a text node
                if (node.nodeValue.match(pattern)) {
                    var mySpan = document.createElement("span");
                    mySpan.innerHTML = "<b>" + node.nodeValue.match(pattern) + "</b>";
                    node.parentNode.replaceChild(mySpan, node);
                }

            } else if(node.nodeType === 1) { // Element node
                findAndReplace(node);
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="javascript:findAndReplace(document);">
    <form name="myform" action="test" method="POST">
    <div align="center"><br>
    <input type="radio" name="group1" value="Milk" /> Milk.txt<br />
    <input type="radio" name="group1" value="Butter" checked /> Butter.txt<br />
    <input type="radio" name="group1" value="Cheese" /> Cheese.tes
    <hr />
    <input type="radio" name="group2" value="Water"/> /bonjour.tsh<br />
    <input type="radio" name="group2" value="Beer" /> Beer.txt<br />
    <input type="radio" name="group2" value="Wine" checked /> /Milk.txt<br />
    </div>
    /Milk.txt
    </form>
    c:/bonjour/Milk.txt<br />
    c:\test.txt
    </body>
    </html>
```