# How to read data from HTML table starting from specified cell using C#?

Tags: c#, xml, html-table

I have html table which was generated dynamically:

```
 <table id="ReportTab">               
            <tr >
                <td rowspan="2">header_1</td>
                <td colspan="2">header_2</td>
                <td colspan="3">header_3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>header_2.1</td>
                <td>header_2.2</td>
                <td>header_3.1</td>
                <td>header_3.2</td>
                <td>header_3.3</td>                
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>12653</td>
                <td>323</td>
                <td>87</td>
                <td>546</td>
                <td>346</td>
                <td>463</td>              
            </tr>
        </table>
```

I want to export a part of such table to XML file. So I have to start reading values from the 3rd row but I have no idea how to do it.

I use the following code to create XML file:

```
        // create a new blank file
        XmlTextWriter textWriter = new XmlTextWriter(pathToXml, null);
        textWriter.WriteStartDocument();            
        textWriter.Close();

        // write data to the xml document
        XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
        document.Load(pathToXml);

        XmlNode element = document.CreateElement("region");
        document.DocumentElement.AppendChild(element);

        // read value from the table cell
        // I supporse this part of code should be inside the loop
        XmlNode subElement = document.CreateElement("value"); 
        subElement.InnerText = ""; // here I need to put value from the table
        element.AppendChild(subElement); 

        document.Save(pathToXml);
```

I would be glad if somebody could help me to solve this problem. Any ideas are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472162/how-to-read-html-as-xml

Answer (score 0):

You are doing to the hard way.  See code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string XMLdefinition = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>";
            string input = 
                "<table id=\"ReportTab\">" +               
                   "<tr >" +
                       "<td rowspan=\"2\">header_1</td>" +
                       "<td colspan=\"2\">header_2</td>" +
                       "<td colspan=\"3\">header_3</td>" +
                   "</tr>" +
                   "<tr>" +
                       "<td>header_2.1</td>" +
                       "<td>header_2.2</td>" +
                       "<td>header_3.1</td>" +
                       "<td>header_3.2</td>" +
                       "<td>header_3.3</td>" +             
                   "</tr>" +
                   "<tr>" +
                       "<td>12653</td>" +
                       "<td>323</td>" +
                       "<td>87</td>" +
                       "<td>546</td>" +
                       "<td>346</td>" +
                       "<td>463</td>" +              
                   "</tr>" +
               "</table>";

            string XML = XMLdefinition + input;
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(XML);
            doc.Save(FILENAME);
        }
    }
}
​
```