# Doctype in XML file

Tags: xml, doctype

I can't get it done to add a DOCTYPE to my xml sitemap. W3C keeps showing an error that the doctype wasn't found (which is the only error). Further no errors, but whenever I put some doctype at the top of the document it creates a lot of errors, after revalidation. Probably because any doctype I can find is a XHTML or HTML doctype, can't find a XML doctype. Anyone who can help me out here?

Error from w3c:

> No DOCTYPE found! Checking XML syntax only.

Builds the header of the xml file:

```
 $header = '<'.'?'.'xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?'.'>'."\n";
 $header .= "\t".'<urlset ';
 $header .= 'xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">'."\n";
 return $header;
```

xml sitemap:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<url>
    <loc>http://www.url.com/path</loc>
    <priority>1.0</priority>
    <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
    <lastmod>2015-06-05</lastmod>
</url>
</urlset>
```

EDIT:

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Why do you have the doctype commented out, and what are the html elements doing in there?

Comment: There are two syntax errors in your sitemap: `<html` is missing a `>` and the XML declaration needs to look like so: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

Comment: @AndrewMorton my bad, I copied the code from the chrome inspector which comments out the doctype. In the actually source it's not commented, so I'll change that.

Comment: @Pekka웃, my mistake. Changed the code, the HTML code is actually correct in the source, just made a mistake with copy pasting it over here. The only warning I get from W3C is it's missing a doctype... still. I don't get it.

Comment: Added a screenshot. Right click on it and open it in a new tab to get a bigger view.

Comment: @ErikVandeVen You need to remove the <html>, <head>, <body>, </html>, </head> and </body>. The sitemap is XML, not HTML.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5472221/4810628

Comment: I'll never copy code from the inspector again. copied complete code from the source, html head and body blocks are gone. But still only get the doctype error

Comment: Guess I found it, pfff last time I worked with DTD is about 6 years ago, but guess this would be it? Now testing: ```<!DOCTYPE url [
<!ELEMENT url (loc, priority, changefreq, lastmod)>
<!ELEMENT loc (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT priority (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT changefreq (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT lastmod (#PCDATA)>
]>```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it done. I added an inline DTD as DOCTYPE which fixed the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE urlset [
<!ELEMENT urlset (url)+>
<!ELEMENT url (loc, priority, changefreq, lastmod)>
<!ELEMENT loc (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT priority (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT changefreq (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT lastmod (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST urlset xmlns CDATA #REQUIRED>
```

Comment: Why did you not add `]>` at end of this definition?