# Reading web page text content using Xml document

Tags: c#, xml, html

I am trying to read webpage text by using Xml Document:

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
string site = "https://emailhunter.co/search/a-bs.com";
document.Load(site);
string allText = document.InnerText;
```

This is the exception i get:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.dll
>   Additional information: The ';' character, hexadecimal value 0x3B, cannot be included in a name. Line 5, position 383.

I really don't understand what's wrong here. If you can give me some tips, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: The url links not to an xml document this a html document. I think you try to read content from an url secured by a login.

Comment: But HTML document _is_ XML document, isn't it?

Comment: No, HTML isn't XML. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472162/how-to-read-html-as-xml

Comment: The page is not secured by a login

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Html Agility Pack** like written in this post: [What is the best way to parse html in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c)